# How to do nested views in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, view, nested

I read on the Web that I should not do it with Angular, but I really want to do it anyway. So what is the best way with AngularJS?

Comment: use ng-view in parent and ng-include in child

Comment: It is also worth looking into [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular ui.router allows you to have nested views AND parallel views. It's got some great documentation to get you started and a couple of the core AngJS devs have been participating in the issues section.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-view in parent and ng-include in child